# Storing and updating config files for my applications with kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

My application uses a config file. How to push updates to it? How  they should be stored for convenient updates? In volumes?

The pipeline for the app is Git -> CI -> deb repo -> docker registry. So the updates to it is just to tell kubernetes to select a new image.

What to do for the config file? Maybe the same chain and then just spin up an container with NFS on it? Also, the app has to be notified about the parameters change via a SIGHUP. How to add that hook?

Comment: Can you give more details of the problem you're trying to solve? Is the configuration static or dynamic for each image version? Did you check `etcd` or `zookeeper` watches?

Comment: The configuration independent from the version of the application. Don't understand what `etcd` and `zookeeper` do. How they are related to a config file in the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use kubernetes [`configMaps`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/) for configs. Don't bake the configs inside the container image.

You can expose the configs as evironment variable or can be mounted as `volumes` inside pod.

ConfigMap can be generated from a file as well.

In your case it seems like you are reading from config file which is at specific location so you can use `configMap` and then mount this configMap at the same location from where your app will read, so you don't need to make any changes in your app.

And when you need to update the config just update the `configMap` and then the new pods that come up will start reading the config. I don't know how to update the config in running pod, what I have tried is scale up and then scale down.

configMaps: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/

HTH

Comment: Doesn't really makes sense as for me if you can't update the config in a running pod. The only added value is passing env vars (I don't need these) because the containers can't do that themselves.

Comment: If you wanna update config in running pod that means your containers are not fully stateless which is not how your apps should be in containers on k8s. I would recommend making your app stateless so that you feel confident restarting the pods as many number of times as you like.

Comment: why does the k8s tell me what my apps should be? My app has heavy parts that are too costly to restart or to break connections with (it's a multimedia server).